# Retrieve the Textbox field as integer which can be used in <for> loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

In aspx page i have a textbox

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtrandom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In .cs page i am retrieving te value from that text box and converting it into `int` so that it can be used in `for` loop.

In .cs page

```
    int random;
    random = Convert.ToInt16(txtrandom.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < random; i++)
    {
    //other code 
    }
```

But When i am executin it will give error as `Input string was not in correct format`.How to convert it into `int`?

Comment: you may use `int.TryParse(txtrandom.Text, out random)` to see if it can be converted to int.

Comment: what does `txtrandom.Text` contain..show us some sample inputs

Comment: Its just a textfield where i am going to enter some integers.

Comment: @SatwikMn integers with separator or a currency symbol???

Comment: Integers like 2,3,4,5 etc non xero numbers

Comment: Have you tried Convert.ToInt32(<string>)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sf1aw27b.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that "Converting a value to integer must needed the converted value to be an int type". The value entered in the textbox is a type of string so it may be any type.

So first you need to check for a valid INT value. For that you need to do like this

```
int random = 0;            
bool isValidInt = int.TryParse(txtrandom.Text, out random);
```

If conversion is successful then you can use the valid integer value which is now in `random`

And the code will look like (Ref: Hitesh's answer)

```
if (isValidInt)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < random; i++)
    {
      //other code 
    }
}
else
{
   Response.Write("Please enter valid int value in textbox.");
   txtrandom.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks nrsharma for giving more information to Satwik Mn based on my ans.

Answer (score 2):

Plz try below code

```
        int random=0;            
        bool isValidInt = int.TryParse(txtrandom.Text, out random);
        if (isValidInt)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < random; i++)
            {
                //other code 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Please enter valid int value in textbox.");
            txtrandom.Focus();
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use text box as number type and for Int conversion you can use

```
 int someInt;
 int.TryParse(s, out someInt);
```

so return value indiacate whether the conversion Int32 succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

These are the recommended methods..

```
int anInteger;
anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
anInteger = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make sure that only numbers are entered into that text box. so that you are not facing any exception while converting it to an integer value.

Use a `regular expression validator` to make sure that `only Integers are entered into that Textbox` with validation expression `^[0-9]+$`

Also You need to be consistent on what datatype you are using. Use `Int32`

then

```
if(!Textbox1.Text.Equals(""))    // you can take care of "" by using required field validator
{ 
Int32 random = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text);
}
```

Now use this value accordingly.